# When inserting decimal value out of range, MySQL inserts a 99999 value instead of throwing an out of range error

Tags: mysql, sql-insert

I have a test schema as follows:

```
CREATE DATABASE TEST;

USE TEST;

CREATE TABLE TEST(DEC_VALUE DECIMAL(5,2));

INSERT INTO TEST VALUES(111111);
```

But the thing is that instead of throwing an error, MySQL is inserting normally but with a 99999,99 value.

I know that the erroneous insert is because the data is bigger than the datatype, but what do I need to change in order to MySQL throw an `Error 1264: Out of range` instead of the wrong insert?

Thank you!

Comment: The (5,2) part might just be for display. You might need a separate constraint added explicitly. I wonder if you change the column type if the real value starts showing up?

Comment: Execute `select @@sql_mode` and post the result.

Comment: @Patrick87 sorry but I didn't understand what you suggested. What should i change my datatype to?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel it will take a while, since the production DB is very tricky to access. What flag should I be aware of? Will try and test it locally in the meanwhile

Comment: See: [STRICT_TRANS_TABLES](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_strict_trans_tables) and [Strict SQL Mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-strict)

Comment: [Demo - Out of range value for column 'DEC](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9fc2b97c83258fb6e8c91e7f8a0c8187)

Comment: What I'm saying is that the 5,2 part might not be part of the datatype at all, but rather instructions on how to format the values for display. Maybe I'm wrong. What you might need to do is add a constraint stating the bounds for that field.

Comment: @Patrick87 It is a metter of STRICT_MODE

Comment: @PaulSpiegel although I still could not test it in the real DB, disabling `STRICT_TRANS_TABLE` simulated the issue and I am pretty positive this is the cause. Could you answer the question so i can accept it? Thank you very much!

Comment: @LukaszSzozda I was testing this as Paul recommended. @@sql_mode is the issue. Thank you!

Comment: @Patrick87 What you mean is true for integers. Eg. `INT(6)` is the same as `INT(10)`. But for DECIMAL type the values in parentheses really define the range that can be stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable the [STRICT_TRANS_TABLES](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_strict_trans_tables) SQL mode.

See: [Setting the SQL Mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-setting)

> To set the SQL mode at server startup, use the `--sql-mode="modes"`
>   option on the command line, or `sql-mode="modes"` in an option file
>   such as `my.cnf` (Unix operating systems) or `my.ini` (Windows). *`modes`*
>   is a list of different modes separated by commas. To clear the SQL
>   mode explicitly, set it to an empty string using `--sql-mode=""` on
>   the command line, or `sql-mode=""` in an option file.

I would change it in `my.cnf` (or `my.ini` on windows). Just append `,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES`

```
mode="...,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES"
```